# "Ни сном(,) ни духом"

Tags: фразеология, пунктуация

У меня по поводу этой поговорки сразу два вопроса: во-первых, нужна ли тут запятая (вроде, устойчивый оборот), а, во-вторых, что она изначально значила?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запятая не нужна, оборот устойчивый.
Скорее всего это аллюзия на библейские мотивы. Откровения ветхазаветным пророкам сообщались обычно либо во сне, либо с помощью сошедшего на землю духа.
У этой версии есть только один недостаток. Выражение, судя по всему, чисто русское, у него нет аналогов в других языках, что нехарактерно для библейских тем.
Впрочем, по другой версии выражение связано с увлечением спиритизмом, пик которого пришелся на вторую половину XIX века.